# Basic Java Swing - adding JLabels with icons at runtime

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm making a grid containing icons representing a game map, and this grid will sometimes need to be redrawn.
I'm working my way up from the basics.
Here's some code I got working

```
    int i = 1;
    while (i < 50) {
            pnlMap.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(i)));
        i += 1;
    }
```

Now I want the JLabels to display icons, but I can't figure out the syntax for the arguments on `pnl.add()`

I imagine it's something like

`pnlMap.add(new JLabel("").setIcon(new ImageIcon(ClientGUI.class
                .getResource("/resources/wall.jpg"))));`

As you can guess this doesn't work. Error: `The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (void)`

**How do I get the above code to add JLabels with icons?**

(on a separate note, what's this kind of object construction called, where you just "add new JLabel" dynamically rather than initialising it before?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the constructor for a `JLabel`, the `setIcon` function doesn't return anything (or returns `void`). This means your code looks a bit like this:

```
pnlMap.add(void);
```

Which is why that error is being thrown.

Therefore, only a slight modification of your code is needed to make your loop work.

```
int i = 1;
while (i < 50) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel(String.valueOf(i));
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ClientGUI.class .getResource("/resources/wall.jpg")));
    pnlMap.add(label);
    i += 1;
}
```

**Edit:**
In answer to your question about the `new JLabel()` construction in your code. It is, surprisingly, called Dynamic Object Construction.

Comment: Aha who would have thought it'd be so straightforwardly named! Thanks, this has worked.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of assistance :) Could you accept this as an answer?